# How to compare value with other objects in nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

How do I compare nested array values with an object in the parent and delete the object if they do not match? I need to iterate through the entire array to be left with only "modules" in the child which match the parent "module".

[Here is the image of the console to see my array structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DndLz.jpg)

```
for (var i = topicArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
if (topicArray[i].module !== module)
topicArray.splice(i, 1) }
```

Comment: can you also add the "topicArray" code in the post?

Comment: Don't post images of data, post sample of actual data so it can be run through your code to test and improve on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to loop through each item, and simply `filter()` out the non matching modules:

```js
const data = [
  {
    module: 'A',
    topics: [
      { topic: 'something', module: 'A' },
      { topic: 'something else', module: 'B' }
    ]
  },
  {
    module: 'B',
    topics: [
      { topic: 'something', module: 'A' },
      { topic: 'something else', module: 'B' }
    ]
  }
]
    
data.forEach(item => {
  item.topics = item.topics.filter(topic => item.module === topic.module)
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: No worries. Also don't forget to mark answers as correct if you feel they are ;)

Comment: emailed you about some freelance work :) would you be interested?